# Format datepicker title

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, datepicker

I using datepickers

Here is code to load one of it

```
 export function load_datepickers_inline():void {
const search_legs_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker");
const leg_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker").datepicker({
  language: gon.locale,
  classes: 'inline-picker',
  altField: '#search_legs_0_date',
  defaultDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
  minDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
  maxDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: (dateText, inst) => {
    const date = new Date(dateText);
    if (!leg_0_datepicker) { return false; }
    leg_1_datepicker.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    if ($("#search_legs_0_hotel_date").length > 0) {
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
    }
  }
})
```

it works great and show me datepicker, like this

[image]

But I need to format title of it like this

> april,
>   2018

How I can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change title of JQuery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796834/change-title-of-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: It's languuage issue in there, if it language in my question?@DNKROZ

Comment: I don't get your point, you want to change the format/text of the title. The first answer in my linked question shows you exactly how to do that